# How to display collection of subcollections with schema.org?

Tags: schema.org, json-ld, google-rich-snippets

I currently use schema.org to show products within the collection, as on example below. However, I would like to use it also with a collection which has other collections inside instead of products. Do you have an idea what is the right way to do this? Docs seem to lack such information.

**Collection with products example:**

```
<script data-no-instant type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "CollectionPage",
    "description": "",
    "url": "https://store.com/collections/products",
    "name": "Products",
    "mainEntity": {
    "@type": "ItemList",
        "numberOfItems": "3",
        "itemListOrder": "Unordered",
    "itemListElement": [

        {
          "@type": "ListItem",
          "position": 1,
          "url": "https://store.com/products/product-1"
        },
        {
          "@type": "ListItem",
          "position": 2,
          "url": "https://store.com/products/product-2"
        },
        {
          "@type": "ListItem",
          "position": 3,
          "url": "https://store.com/products/product-3"
        }
    ]
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: With "right way", do you mean how to use Schema.org, or do you mean how to qualify for a specific Google rich result?

Comment: I mean how to qualify for a specific Google rich result

Comment: Okay, which rich result do you mean? [Carousels](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/mark-up-listings)?

Comment: Google only document single level lists, so you could assume that's all they support at this time.

Comment: Use `ListItem` `nextItem` and then hang your sub-collection array for that `ListItem` there.